# how do I solve Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function for yarn webpack

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I'm going roundin circles, i have jquery working with most of my code. I transitioned from uglify.js using yarn encore with webpack.

Which file do I include, previously had the following which worked, how do I add the css files as well.

```
  jquery-1.8.3.js
  jquery-ui.js
  jquery.form.js 
  jquery
```

currently I have in my app.js

```
require('../css/app.css');

// require jQuery normally other won't work
const $ = require('jquery');

 // create global $ and jQuery variables
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

require('jquery-ui');

require('jquery-form');
```

These added these manually

```
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="
      {{asset('bundles/site/css/mobiledatepicker.css')}}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="
      {{asset('bundles/site/css/jquerymobile.css')}}">
```

Comment: Is your webpack configured properly for jquery/jqueryui?

Comment: you got me thinking it was more a widget see my answer

Answer (score 3):

after bit more digging I found the answer

```
   require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js');
```